# Is there a way to annotate the parameter and return value in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

```
parent(mel, joan).
parent(jane, betty).
parent(jane, tom).
parent(richard, adam).
parent(richard, rosa).
parent(joan, fran).
```

For example someone asks me to find all ancestors of a parent. I give him the code:

```
ancestor(P,C) :- parent(P, C).
ancestor(P,C) :- ancestor(P,P1), parent(P1, C).
```

But my friend still doesn't know how to use the predicate. Does he call it like

`ancestor(richard, C)` or `ancestor(C, richard)` ?

Is there a way to annotate that `P` is the parameter while `C` is the return value? And in a complex case, there will be predicates with different names, how should my user know which predicate is the final predicate he wants to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help the human-readable meaning, you could add an extra predicate documenting the parameters as readable name/value pairs:

```
entry_ancestor_of(ancestor=P, descendent=C) :-
    ancestor(P,C).

?- entry_ancestor_of(ancestor=richard, descendent=C).
C = adam .
```

Above, the suffix *ancestor_of* suggests param 1 is ancestor of param 2, so naming the predicate carefully can make it clearer.

Usually(convention), input parameters are the earlier parameters, and output parameters are later parameters, but where the predicate 'works both ways', ie. either could be input or output, this rule can't hold.  This is the case for your predicate:

```
?- entry_ancestor_of(ancestor=X, descendent=adam).
X = richard .
```

Either parameter could be input or output, so there is no need to codify/explain them as such, although you might want to comment that it works both ways.

I would usually comment these 'flexible' predicates by putting an example of both of the above usages in a comment next to the predicate.

For entrypoint labelling, just do one or more of the following:

- explicitly name the predicate as an entrypoint, as above
- document using comments in the code which are the entrypoints
- arrange the entrypoints in the same physical section with a comment
  block saying that the predicates below are entrypoints.

**Edit: Extra things re: coding guidelines / other answers.**

1. In [Coding guidelines for Prolog](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2899), section 3.8, it says 'For example, mother_of(A, B) is ambiguous;', so I gave bad advice on that.. perhaps acapelli's suggestion would be more useful on that.

In that document, also have a look at:

- 3.5 Choose sensible names for auxiliary predicates
- 3.8 Choose predicate names to help show the argument order
- 3.13 Decide whether predicate names should carry the types on which they operate
- 4.1 Begin every predicate (except perhaps auxiliary predicates) with an introductory comment in a well-defined format

The '?' system for identifying parameter types that will ness mentioned is on page 21.

Comment: So you use "entry" prefix to denote the "main function"?

Comment: I just used that as an example.. definitely not a convention. Perhaps the entrypoint should be as capellic suggests, and other 'helper' predicates that are similarly named could be suffixed '_aux or '_loop' - the guidelines above cover advice on that area as well.

Comment: @LoveRight - please would you be kind enough to uptick (ie. give credit) to the other answers - both of which were instrumental in arriving at this answer.

Answer (score 1):

a useful *convention*, sponsored for instance by [Markus Triska](http://www.logic.at/prolog/), builds a predicate functor by joining the parameters 'names' - in a wide, applicable sense. Your example could be

```
parent_child(mel, joan).
...

ancestor_descendant(P, C) :- parent_child(P, C).
ancestor_descendant(A, D) :- ancestor_descendant(A, I), parent_child(I, D).
```

Also ISO-Prolog, and - for instance - SWI-Prolog library, attempt to follow this strategy.

For instance

```
atom_codes(Atom, Codes) :- ...
```

WRT to declare the *type* and *status* of arguments, some Prolog provide declarations - for instance Turbo Prolog, ECLiPSe, others... Sometime such declarations are required - usually to check correctness, often to speed up the computation.

SWI-Prolog offers 'just' structured comments, that IDE process automatically, and there has been a [contribution](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=mavis) aiming to exploit such declarations with runtime check.

Comment: Which systems are you aware of where optional declarations speed up the computation? In DECsystem 10 Prolog, the declarations primarily reduced space consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with comments, and/or meaningful argument names,

```
% ancestor( ?Ancestor, ?Descendent).
ancestor(P,C) :- parent(P, C).
ancestor(P,C) :- ancestor(P,P1), parent(P1, C).
```

`?` means the argument can be used both as input (already set when the call is made), or for output (not yet set when the call is made).

The convention promoted in The Art of Prolog (I think) is that you place the name of the predicate after its first argument, to get at the intended argument ordering: `P` "is" `ancestor` `C`. Presumably "ancestor_of". But if you use that name, someone unfamiliar with that convention  might read `ancestor_of(P,C)` as "ancestor of P is C", so it's a double-edged sword.

Comment: @false that's just my own personal take on this, not based on anyone else's opinion.

Comment: @false I think with "of" the wrong reading is more natural. without it both feel the same, so it's easier to switch to the learned pattern of `A is_pred B`.